# Specification Vs Framework Theory

Tags: frameworks, theory

What is the difference between Specification and Framework with some examples ?

Is JSF a framework or a specification ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Definitions in one sentence:**

A specification is an explicit set of rules that define *how* to implement a use case.

A framework facilitates and structures the *actual* implementation of a use case.

**Cake analogy:**

If a cake recipe is a specification, a [cake mix](http://www.amazon.de/Betty-Crocker-Sunny-Lemon-Cupcake/dp/B00856ZGM8/ref=sr_1_23?ie=UTF8&qid=1432135727&sr=8-23&keywords=cake%20mix) is a framework.

**Examples:**

[Spring](https://spring.io) is a framework to create web applications (among other things)

[JSR-250](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=250) is a specification for Java annotations.

JSF is the [specification](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr314/index.html) of a framework, of which there are several widely-used [implementations](https://javaserverfaces-spec-public.java.net/)